# Structure dereference operator (operator->)

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, operator-overloading

I am writing a thin template wrapper for iterators, and hit a stumbling block when passing through the structure dereference operator, mainly because pointers don't have one:

```
#include <vector>

struct mystruct {
    int member;
};

template<class iterator>
struct wrap {
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::pointer pointer;
   iterator internal;
   pointer operator->() {return internal.operator->();} //MARK1
};

int main() {
    wrap<std::vector<mystruct>::iterator> a;
    a->member;
    wrap<mystruct*> b;
    b->member;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/XdvEz

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘typename std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::pointer wrap<iterator>::operator->() [with iterator = mystruct*]’:
prog.cpp:18:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:11: error: request for member ‘operator->’ in ‘((wrap<mystruct*>*)this)->wrap<mystruct*>::internal’, which is of non-class type ‘mystruct*’
```

This following method works, but I don't think it's guaranteed to work.  Namely, if an iterator has a strange `pointer` type that isn't the same as a pointer to a `value_type`.

```
   pointer operator->() {return &*internal;} //MARK3
```

Comment: What version of C++ has a *structure dereference operator*?

Comment: Why `char*`? Wouldn't there be some sort of `Iterator::value_type` somewhere?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That's what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) calls it.  The C++ standard just calls it `operator->`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to return - a reference to the object, or the iterator, or a pointer to the object? Yes, don't write pseudo-code, but *minimal, representative code*.

Comment: Wouldn't template specialization be the right way to do it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Replaced `char` with `mystruct` that has a member.  Question should make sense now.  I didn't realize it didn't make sense, because IDEone was giving me the expected error message.

Comment: @AzzA: If template specialization is required, that's an option, but I feel like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I'm glad I discovered the term _structure dereference operator_ since '->' is impossible to Google for :P.

Comment: @AzzA: As it turns out, I went with specialization, since I needed a homogeneous return type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard indirectly says that an overloaded `operator->` has to either return a pointer, an object that is convertible to a pointer, or an object that has overloaded `operator->`. Your best bet is to just return `internal`.

`§13.5.6 [over.ref] p1`

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m`

(The above applies recursively.)

Comment: And before you ask about `operator*()`, return type is `iterator_traits<iterator>::reference` and return just `*iterator`. Any iterator that does not return a `reference` on dereference doesn't model the iterator concept correctly and can be savely ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I got `operator*`, but it never dawned on me to return a `iterator` instead of a `pointer`.  Thanks!  I expect this is the answer but I'll try to give it a day or so for other suggestions.

Comment: I would just add, that the recursion ends when a pointer is returned (or an object convertible to a pointer), so if operator-> returns a pointer you've hit the recursion base case and you're done.  If operator-> returns something else with an operator-> overload, then you recurse.  This may seem obvious, but it took me a while to sort it out.